# LinearLayout Layout Params not Refreshing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, parallax, redraw

I'm experiencing a rare behavior and I can't figure out why.

I'm implementing a fading action bar with a parallax effect and a custom "on-pull-update". All of this effects plays with the image header's height and position, creating a sensation of parallax and bouncinnes.

Everything works fine but after a couple of plays, going up and down, Image header's Linear Layout doesnt refresh o reflect the height changes even when I Log from the event Listener and size/pos/alpha calculations work fine.

Is there something im missing that prevents the view from refresing multiple times or such?

Below my main class wich heredate from a custom "ObservableActionBar" which only overrides the onScroll function adding a listener through a simple interface wichs expects 5 parameters.

```
public class ActivityTest extends Activity{

private Drawable mActionBarBackgroundDrawable;

//PARALLAX
private float scale;

private boolean isGoingDownOnCero = false;

private float onDownY = 0;

private float distanceY = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_test);
            
    mActionBarBackgroundDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_background);
    mActionBarBackgroundDrawable.setAlpha(0);
    
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(mActionBarBackgroundDrawable);
    
    scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    
    ((ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_test))
        .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                isGoingDownOnCero = true;
                onDownY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                isGoingDownOnCero = false;
                ((View) findViewById(R.id.anchor)).setLayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        (int)(255 * scale)
                    )
                );
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                distanceY = (event.getY() - onDownY) / 2;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    ((ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_test))
        .setScrollViewListener(new ScrollViewListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
                    int oldx, int oldy) {
                
                    
                    int headerHeight = findViewById(R.id.image_header).getHeight() - getActionBar().getHeight();
                    float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), headerHeight) / headerHeight;
                    int newAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);
                    mActionBarBackgroundDrawable.setAlpha(newAlpha);
                    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(mActionBarBackgroundDrawable);

                    //findViewById(R.id.image_header).offsetTopAndBottom( - offset);
                                        
                    int cantRedrawSize = (int)(
                            ((int)(y * scale) / 2) < ( (int)(255 * scale) / 2) ? 
                                    (int)(y * scale) / 2 : 
                                    ((int)(255 * scale) / 2) );
                    
                    Log.v("REDRAW SIZE", cantRedrawSize + "");
                    Log.v("Linear SIZE", ((View) findViewById(R.id.anchor)).getHeight() + "");
                    
                    ((View) findViewById(R.id.anchor)).setLayoutParams(
                        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            (255 * scale) - cantRedrawSize > 0 ? (int)((255 * scale) - cantRedrawSize) : 0 
                        )
                    );
                    
                    
                    if(isGoingDownOnCero && y == oldy && y == 0){
                        ((View) findViewById(R.id.anchor)).setLayoutParams(
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                (int)(255 * scale) + ( distanceY > 0 ? distanceY < 200 ? (int)distanceY : 200 : 0)
                            )
                        );                  
                    }
                    
                    ((View) findViewById(R.id.anchor)).requestLayout();
                    
                    
            }
                   
        });     
} 
}
```

And my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.noche.quepasoanoche.ActivityTest" >

<com.example.CLASS.ObservableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            
            

           <LinearLayout
               android:background="#000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/anchor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="255dp" >
                
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_home" />
               
            </LinearLayout>
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/item_lista"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
                android:background="#000"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</com.example.CLASS.ObservableScrollView>
```

And how it looks.

[image]

Comment: It's possible that you are getting an ACTION_CANCEL prior to the ACTION_UP and it leaves the view in a bad state. You could add ACTION_CANCEL to your ACTION_UP switch case and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you i will give a try and post my results here.

Comment: Its unrelated to any fingers action event since im making changes from an implementation of onScroll event provided by ScrollView. Changes should happen with every new move. Im really lost here.

Answer (score 0):

call this `((View) findViewById(R.id.anchor)).requestLayout();` in the `onTouch` function after you set the height of the view:

Comment: Ive done it, and even when im calling it i cant achieve such behavior. I mean even if i dont call requestLayout, the linear layout responds a couple of time before getting stuck. Thank you.